# expecting to have received with nil

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Rspec question

having

```
puts x.y
x.y = nil
```

I want to test if this line has been executed

so something like

```
allow(x).to receive(:y) { 'abc' }
```

and then

```
expect(x).to have_received(:y).with nil
```

but with(nil) doesn't work

any suggestions?

I want to make sure y is set to nil, but I cannot just check the value since I am stubbing x.y beforehand

Comment: Why would you want to ensure that something is set to an explicit `nil`? That seems like a code smell to me.

Comment: Also, if y is set to nil, then calling `x.y` will give you a `NoMethodError`. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you create a gist with the complete rspec code?

Comment: I agree with the code smell, but before removing the smell i am trying to fix this as I am trying to learn now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to assert that

```
x.y(nil)
```

is called.

To assert that the method `y=` is called with `nil` parameter, you'd want to use the `:y=` symbol instead.

```
allow(x).to receive(:y=){ "xyz" }
expect(x).to have_received(:y=).with(nil)
```

Comment: should it be allow(x).to receive(:y){ "xyz" } ?

Comment: 0x007fc7e336a968> does not implement: y=

Comment: Then you need to show us more code. I can only make guesses about your implementation based on what you've pasted. Can you create a small sample gist that fully shows what you are attempting?

Comment: just allow(x).to receive(:y=) is enough